# PHP function undefined when included by jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function

Alrighty,

I have an error module which is basically just a styled div that has a call to a PHP function for printing out errors.

It works perfectly when I include it like this:

```
<?php if(!empty($errors)){
include 'includes/modules/error.mod.php';           
 }else if(!empty($success)){
include 'includes/modules/success.mod.php';
 }?>
```

But I am now trying to make it flashier with jQuery and so I'm including it with a jQuery function:

```
function errorModule(){
$.get('includes/modules/error.mod.php', function(data){
        var errorModule = $(data).hide();
        errorModule.appendTo($('#navMain')).show('blind', 1500);
     });
}
```

Now, it works most of the way. The error module appears like I want it too. However the PHP function that once worked perfectly is now 'undefined.'

Why?

EDIT: Contents of error.mod.php

```
<div id="errorModule">
<p class="h2">The Following Errors Have Occured:</p>
<?php
    echo outputArray($errors);      
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the content of includes/modules/error.mod.php?

Comment: Updated with error.mod.php contents. :)

Comment: How does the PHP parser know about `$errors` when the file is loaded with `$.get()`?

Comment: Why would I append the error module to itself? I'm placing it below the navigation bar of my site so that it looks as if it's sliding down from it.

Comment: $errors is an array in my init.php file. Every page has it included on the top.

Comment: But not in error.mod.php when it's not included within another file.

Comment: The orignal, served page's PHP environment is irretrievable deep history by the time `$.get()` requests the `error.mod.php`. PHP scripts written as includes can't have a life of their own if they depend on being included server-side!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AJAX call (the purpose of `$.get`) is not like an `include`, it is a separate web request to the URL provided. So in this case, what is being fetched by `$.get` is the same as what will load if you point your browser at `includes/modules/error.mod.php` - a good way of debugging AJAX is to do exactly that.

Based on the file name, I suspect this is not what you intended, and that this file is not meant to be loaded on its own.

To use AJAX, what you would need is a new PHP page, say `ajax_message_output.php`, which performs the necessary processing to output the "module" onto the page. Note that this page won't have any of the data from the "parent" page - so, for instance, `$errors` will not have the same value in your new `ajax_message_output.php` that it had on the main page.

If all you're trying to do is display the errors *from the main page load*, but make them look "flashier", AJAX is not the technology you want. To make them slide down, just have them initially hidden (using `<div id="messages" style="display: none;">...</div>` or similar) and have `$('#messages').show('blind', 1500)` run when the page loads.

Comment: `which performs the necessary processing, whatever that might be` the key element to the answer lies within a simple sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm not sure I'm following completely. I'm still fairly inexperienced at a lot of this. I could use a little more clarity. Also, is this the efficient way for me to achieve my goal or should I be employing a different method of displaying this module?

Comment: @Nifty62 I've expanded the answer based on your edits to the question

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I have some ideas. I will do some experimenting based on your suggestions and let you know. I really appreciate the help guys!